# Android position View at runtime

Tags: android, view, runtime, android-relativelayout

i move an image on the screen and control if the object collide with an rectangle. If it happen I set the touchlistener(null) and set the position to the position of the rectangle. But the View will not be placed there.

I tried this:

```
view.layout(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
```

and this:

```
LayoutParams mlp = (LayoutParams) aimView.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(rect.left, rect.top, 0, 0);
view.setLayoutParams(mlp);
```

I also tested with getRelativeLeft((View) view.getParent()) and add it to the left and top, but no effect.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you move image with finger ?

Comment: yeah and when the object intersect the rectangle i dismiss the ontouchlistener and want to position the view automatically to the right place

Comment: in the center of rectangle right?

Comment: no that's no important. If the view contacts with the invisible rect. Then it should be moved to the place of the rect automatically.
The movement with the finger is no problem. The placing of the view to the new place is the problem.